# How do I restrict a role from not seeing prices on Products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan, rolify

I have a `Product` model, and if a user is either logged in as a `guest` role, or not logged in, I don't want them to be able to see the prices on the products in my app.

I am using Devise, CanCan and Rolify.

I tried this, in my `ability.rb`:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.has_role? :guest
  can :read, [Product, Vendor, Banner]
  cannot :read, [Product.price]      
end
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I haven't added any code to my views - do I need to do that, or should this `ability` class just not show the prices at all?

Comment: you can't do this using cancan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking back what I said. You can somehow do this using CanCan but it seems like a stretch.
Can you try the following?

```
if user.has_role? :guest
  can :read, [Product, Vendor, Banner]
  cannot :view_prices, Product
end
```

Then in your view, you have to manually check if the user can view prices

```
<% if can? :view_prices, Product %>
  <%= product.price %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I get this error: `NoMethodError at /
undefined method 'price' for #<Class:0x007feb523fe518>` at line `cannot :read, [Product.price]`.

Comment: ah sorry, I copied your code but forgot to remove that line. updated my answer

Comment: Perfect....this works. Any thoughts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407491/how-do-i-restrict-the-currently-logged-in-user-to-only-see-products-that-belong ?