# How do I restrict the currently logged in user to only see products that belong to them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan, rolify

If a user is logged in with a specific role - `vendor` - they should only see items that they have created in their store. They should not be able to see products from other vendors.

So I am trying to do this in my authorization (using Devise, CanCan, Rolify).

I tried this:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.has_role? :vendor
  can :dashboard
  can :manage, [Product, Vendor], :vendor_id => user.id
  can :view, [Product], :vendor_id => user.id
end
```

But....haven't had much luck with that...what am I missing?

**Edit 1**

I know that I can restrict the products in the controller like:

```
 @product = current_user.products
```

But that's not what I am looking for. In this case, a vendor (i.e. user with role `:vendor`) should only be able to see products they added to the store, but they shouldn't be able to see products that other vendors add. However, a buyer (i.e. a user with role `:buyer`) should be able to see all the products from all buyers (as will an admin/etc). A buyer won't be able to see the prices, and some other attributes on some of the products, etc.

How can I achieve all of that?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `can :read` instead of `can :view`

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you can only find the products belonging to that user.

```
def show
  @product = @user.products.find(params[:id])
  ...
```

Same applies to edit and update action. Cancan in this case is not required.

Comment: I know that...but there are some sections of the site that they should not have access to - e.g. 1 vendor should not be able to see the product catalog of another vendor. Even though, a buyer, should be able to see all products from all vendors. If I were to put that logic in my controllers, I would have to write custom logic for every action and every role...right? There must be another way to do that.